# Can't compile latex document

Tags: latex

Can't compile an old document of my CV that requires additional latex libraries. Can someone recommend a tex variant that should handle it.

tried
latex

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
```

luatex

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                [a4paper,10pt]{article}
```

xetex

```
I can't find the format file `xetex.fmt'!
```

Latex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section
\usepackage{supertabular}

%Styling Itemizations
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\setitemize[1]{labelindent=\parindent, label=$\triangleright$}

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%Tweak a bit the top margin
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}
```

Comment: As the message says, try with xelatex or lualatex. Some packages are incompatible with old latex.

Comment: yes I have tried with both. The error messages are in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

worked fine compiling with
xelatex